# What files to upload when making a change in a webpage?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have my website offsite at an ISP.

What I remember from when I programmed ASP.NET last time in 2005, if you make a page change, you have to upload the page files and what's in the BIN folder.

Is this still the case for Visual Studio 2010?

Regards
Tea

Comment: Ofcourse!! All latest will go on server.

Comment: Bin contents only need to be upload if you make changes to you code behind files or if you have set your aspx files to be compiled. If you are only making changes to the aspx you can just upload that one file.

Comment: Thanks to all that replied!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing only particular files on production environment is never a good idea. You should consider using Publish option awailable from VS Solution Explorer (even if Publish is done into temporary folder and then manualy copied into production). This way you will ensure your development/test version match production and avoid any potential suprises.

Comment: Though I do agree with other answers, I prefer this one because you never know what you will miss. One day you'll upload just that page and nothing will work. I know how annoying it is to check that web.config file but at least you run through it and double check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is still the case, regardless of your development environment.

Chris