# How to create or attach WCF service in existing asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net, wcf, deployment

i have already a web site which is live and hosted in ORCS Web developed using asp.net form project type. now i am planning to develop a wcf service which will be stored in a new folder of my existing website. we will use wcf service for uploading file from client machine to our web server. client can be any other .net based web apps or .net based win apps. i never work with wcf in production environment. so i want to know can i create that wcf service which will be stored in a new folder of my web site or do i need to host that wcf service separately.

if i can store the wcf service in my existing web site then how to deploy it? if i copy the dll file of my site and svc in our web server after development and testing then it would be sufficient or not for creating proxy from client side. actually any how i have to create wcf service in my site. i can not deploy the wcf service separately out of my website. so guide me how to deploy and what are the files i need to copy to my web server because first time i will be going to do this. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add wcf service to existing asp.net application.
Open solution explorer right click on asp.net app project and select "Add" -> "New Item" and then select "WCF Service".

VS will modify your web.config by adding something similar to this, wcf server configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And now about deploying solution. It's never a good idea to do partial deploy. Please read one of my posts about this subject [What files to upload when making a change in a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911916/what-files-to-upload-when-making-a-change-in-a-webpage/13912681#13912681)

Comment: i just ask do i need to upload .svc file with folder structure alsong with project dll file...plzz guide. thanks

Comment: Yes, svc and dll files are required. And don't forget to modify web.config with system.serviceModel.

Comment: what modification ur talking about web.config with system.serviceModel. u said required line would be added automatically in web.config file.

Comment: when we host wcf service in my web site then what are the bindings & behavior it will support? what are the restriction would be there when one host wcf in IIS. please guide me. thanks

Comment: Yes, web.config will be automaticly populated with system.serviceModel section inside VS project. If you will also copy web.config then this will not be something to worry about. About the bindings, there are several different types, but in your case for IIS you should use "basicHttpBinding", "wsHttpBinding", "WSDualHttpBinding" or "WSFederationHttpBinding". I would advice you to start with "basicHttpBinding". Please visit folowing link for more details about different types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx

Comment: i am very new in wcf...so asking what is difference between basicHttpBinding and  WSDualHttpBinding and WSFederationHttpBinding. which one should be best when service will be host along with asp.net apps. does the above 3 binding support duplex??

Comment: Yes WSDualHttpBinding is for duplex support. If you are planing to have one IIS based wcf service and n wcf clients you should start with basicHttpBinding.

Comment: yes i have plant to host my wcf along with my asp.net project and multiple client like other web apps and windows apps will consume it.i am not sure if i use basicHttpBinding then does it support duplex binding? because duplex would be my choice and also i like send self certificate for security reason and membership based authentication. i think i should go for two binding one would be  WSDualHttpBinding and another is nettcp binding. so what will be your suggestion. thanks

Comment: basicHttpBinding does not support duplex binding so in your case I guess the best option would be wsDualHttpBinding. With this type you will be able to handle win and web wcf clients with same configuration. I would keep it simple. On last project I was using wsHttpBinding hosted on IIS and it performed real well even for large data requests. Maybe one interesting info about this project. Before wcf I was using .net remoting on this same project. It's true that wcf had 5-7 times slower responses than .net remoting, but the response times were still so small that this doesn't matter.